# Exporting Android Library - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, shared-libraries, android-library

I created an Android Library in Android studio. I now want to make it available for others to use it. It uses Google Play Services and a drawable (drawable isnt necessary). My issue is I can only find reading on importing libraries, not exporting them.

I want to make this library downloadable. Does anyone have steps to exporting it and packaging it so people can reference it in a build.gradle file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582?utm_source=Tuts+&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=WeeklyDigest&utm_content=WeeklyDigest-20150903&WT.mc_id=Tuts+_email_WeeklyDigest-20150903

Comment: Publish it as an aar in maven or jcenter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) is probably the easiest method of publishing artefacts, assuming your repository is on Github. All you need to do is alter the build.gradle in the project referencing the library to something like below, then sync your gradle files:

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.MyUser:MyRepo:-SNAPSHOT'
    }
```

Behind the scenes this results in Jitpack grabbing the library source from Github, building it, then allowing you to download it. It's possible to specify releases by using tags in Github - the example given just uses the latest commit.